# A question about structure of class component in React

Tags: reactjs

As we know, the structure of a class component can be simplified as the following:

```
// Blank 1

class Books extends Component {

    // Blank 2

    render(){

        // Blank 3

        return()

    }

export default Books;
```

So just for example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateFilters } from '../../../services/filters/actions';
import Checkbox from '../../Checkbox';
import GithubStarButton from '../../github/StarButton';

import './style.scss';

const availableSizes = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'ML', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'];

class Filter extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    updateFilters: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    filters: PropTypes.array
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.selectedCheckboxes = new Set();
  }

  toggleCheckbox = label => {
    if (this.selectedCheckboxes.has(label)) {
      this.selectedCheckboxes.delete(label);
    } else {
      this.selectedCheckboxes.add(label);
    }

    this.props.updateFilters(Array.from(this.selectedCheckboxes));
  };

  createCheckbox = label => (
    <Checkbox
      classes="filters-available-size"
      label={label}
      handleCheckboxChange={this.toggleCheckbox}
      key={label}
    />
  );

  createCheckboxes = () => availableSizes.map(this.createCheckbox);

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="filters">
        <h4 className="title">Sizes:</h4>
        {this.createCheckboxes()}
        <GithubStarButton />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  filters: state.filters.items
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { updateFilters }
)(Filter);
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchProducts } from '../../services/shelf/actions';
import { addProduct } from '../../services/cart/actions';

import Product from './Product';
import Filter from './Filter';
import ShelfHeader from './ShelfHeader';
import Clearfix from '../Clearfix';
import Spinner from '../Spinner';

import './style.scss';

class Shelf extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    fetchProducts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    products: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    addProduct: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    filters: PropTypes.array,
    sort: PropTypes.string
  };

  state = {
    loading: false
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    const { filters, sort } = this.props;

    this.handleFetchProducts(filters, sort);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { filters: nextFilters, sort: nextSort } = nextProps;

    if (nextFilters !== this.props.filters) {
      this.handleFetchProducts(nextFilters, undefined);
    }

    if (nextSort !== this.props.sort) {
      this.handleFetchProducts(undefined, nextSort);
    }
  }

  handleFetchProducts = (
    filters = this.props.filters,
    sort = this.props.sort
  ) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    this.props.fetchProducts(filters, sort, () => {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { products } = this.props;

    const p = products.map(p => {
      return (
        <Product product={p} addProduct={this.props.addProduct} key= 
   {p.id} />
      );
    });

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.loading && <Spinner />}
        <Filter />
        <div className="shelf-container">
          <ShelfHeader productsLength={products.length} />
          {p}
          <Clearfix />
        </div>
        <Clearfix />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  products: state.shelf.products,
  filters: state.filters.items,
  sort: state.sort.type
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchProducts, addProduct }
)(Shelf);
```

Except for `state` and life cycle methods, sometimes we define other types of attributes and functions in `Blank 1`, sometimes in `Blank 2`, sometimes in `Blank 3`. So I am wondering when we are going to define attributes and functions, which part should we choose? Is there a convention or something like that?

Comment: blank 3 will run on every render - excessive.  blank 2 is for context-specific or inherited props/methods.  blank 1 is best for functions to be re-usable, testable and accessible between components without the component dependency itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block 1 is for defining variables and functions which are not depended on component ,these are general variables and functions which could be used in the component and can even be exported in another files.

Block 2 is for defining component specific variables and methods, define lifecycle methods.variables and methods defined in block 2 could be accessed using this keyword.

Block 3 is used when we want to execute certain piece of code,every time when render method is executed.Apart from initial render, render method is executed every time when setState is performed,so avoid writing code in block 3 as it's excessive.

Hope this helps,

Cheers !!